# Understanding GC in python

Tags: python-3.x, garbage-collection

I'm reading https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/ (and https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/gc.html) to understand the mechanism behind GC in python. The concept of generation thresholds is somehow unclear to me. The mentioned article (and many others) says that

> Generations are collected when the number of objects that they contain reaches some predefined threshold

The default thresholds are (700, 10, 10). Fine.

I'm running the following code to better understand the mechanism and the output contradicts with what I understand as the definition of the thresholds:

```
class A():
    pass

lst = []
gc_lst = []

def strt(p, inf):
    s = "phase = %s\ninf = %s\ngc.get_count() = %s\ngc.get_stats() = %s\nlen(gc.get_objects()) = %s"\
        %(p, inf, gc.get_count(), gc.get_stats(), [len(gc.get_objects(0)),len(gc.get_objects(1)),len(gc.get_objects(2))])
    gc_lst.append(s)

gc.callbacks.append(strt)
s = "gc.get_count() = %s\ngc.get_stats() = %s\nlen(gc.get_objects() for each gen) = %s"\
%(gc.get_count(), gc.get_stats(), [len(gc.get_objects(0)),len(gc.get_objects(1)),len(gc.get_objects(2))])
print(s)

for k in range(8000):
    lst.append(A())
    gc_lst.append(k)

for k in gc_lst:
    print(k)
```

the output:

```
0
1
2
...
...
...
5413
5414
phase = start
inf = {'generation': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}
gc.get_count() = (701, 8, 1)
gc.get_stats() = [{'collections': 19, 'collected': 65, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 33, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}]
len(gc.get_objects()) = [703, 5475, 5069]
phase = stop
inf = {'generation': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}
gc.get_count() = (0, 9, 1)
gc.get_stats() = [{'collections': 20, 'collected': 65, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 33, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}]
len(gc.get_objects()) = [2, 6176, 5069]
5415
5416
...
6114
6115
phase = start
inf = {'generation': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}
gc.get_count() = (701, 9, 1)
gc.get_stats() = [{'collections': 20, 'collected': 65, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 33, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}]
len(gc.get_objects()) = [703, 6176, 5069]
phase = stop
inf = {'generation': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}
gc.get_count() = (0, 10, 1)
gc.get_stats() = [{'collections': 21, 'collected': 65, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 33, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}]
len(gc.get_objects()) = [2, 6877, 5069]
6116
6117
...
6815
6816
phase = start
inf = {'generation': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}
gc.get_count() = (701, 10, 1)
gc.get_stats() = [{'collections': 21, 'collected': 65, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 33, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}]
len(gc.get_objects()) = [703, 6877, 5069]
phase = stop
inf = {'generation': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}
gc.get_count() = (0, 11, 1)
gc.get_stats() = [{'collections': 22, 'collected': 65, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 33, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}]
len(gc.get_objects()) = [2, 7578, 5069]
6817
6818
...
7516
7517
phase = start
inf = {'generation': 1, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}
gc.get_count() = (701, 11, 1)
gc.get_stats() = [{'collections': 22, 'collected': 65, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 33, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}]
len(gc.get_objects()) = [703, 7578, 5069]
phase = stop
inf = {'generation': 1, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}
gc.get_count() = (0, 0, 2)
gc.get_stats() = [{'collections': 22, 'collected': 65, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 2, 'collected': 33, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 0, 'collected': 0, 'uncollectable': 0}]
len(gc.get_objects()) = [2, 0, 13341]
7518
7519
...
7998
7999
```

I see that the mentioned thresholds are for collections, and not objects in generation. The younger generation is collected each 700 objects. the next generation is collected each 10 collections of the young gen (each 7000 objects) and following this logic the oldest gen should be collected each 70000 objects (neglecting the fix for the quadratic time issue https://bugs.python.org/issue4074). What am I missing in the definition?